# Convert lineString to MultilineString in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry

How can I convert the line string to multiline string in PostGIS?
I have converted geometry points to line string by this: `st_makeline(location.shape)`
but by this command:

```
  SELECT uuid_generate_v4()                                         AS uuid,
          j."deviceId",
         st_astext(st_linemerge(st_union(j.shape))) AS multiLine
  FROM j
  group by date, j."deviceId" ;
```

I got this results:

[image]

It's result is again **line string**?

Comment: Perhaps your GROUP BY returns only one geometry per group. ST_Union and ST_Linemerge do not change a single linestring into MultiLinestring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried ST_Multi?
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html

```
select st_astext(st_multi(st_geometryfromtext('LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)')))
```

> MULTILINESTRING((30 10,10 30,40 40))

For you this would be

```
 SELECT uuid_generate_v4()                                         AS uuid,
      j."deviceId",
     st_astext(st_multi(st_linemerge(st_union(j.shape)))) AS multiLine
FROM j
  group by date, j."deviceId" ;
```

Comment: Tank's it's work.