# Breaking LineString into MultilineString group by distance between two points and it's time

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, linestring

This is line string of my geometry column that created by postgis and shown in qgis:
[image]

This is multiline string like above:
[image]

I am new on gis and How can i do break line and convert it into multiline?
I have converted geometry to multiline by this code:

```
st_astext(st_multi(st_linemerge(st_union(j.shape)))) as multiLine
```

but there is just one line as a `MULTILINESTRING`.it is like `MULTILINESTRING((xx yy , aa rr))`.How can i do break for example by distance between two points and creation date time for breaking line?
Is it possible?

Comment: how exactly do you want that line segmented? seeing your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/294885/93656), are you looking for a *MultLinestring* consisting of single *Linestrings* between GPS points? if so, these points do have a `date` column with a timestamp of the points collection?

Comment: I think i made a mistake. look , i have geometry column with it's timestamp, now how could i create multilinestring by check distance and timestamp between points?Means for example if distance between 2 points more than 200 meters and timestamp more than 1 min ,created other line in multiline string...this is my pg code http://codepad.org/wyesDSCX  @ThingumaBob

Comment: this is main table http://pasteall.org/pic/d803392cbb031cc63d66a6d8217c10fb -> `olocayions` 
 @ThingumaBob

Comment: After reading your last two comments i believe you will have to solve this in python. You need to create a new column "trip_id" for example and assign each point an ID based on some IF ELSE conditions. "if time > X min since last point, give it a new ID" ect. There is no spatial tool that will break up the line as you require.

Comment: There is not other way to solve that without using other language? Is it possible do just with postgres. @Marshall

Comment: I am sure other languages can do this also because you just need looping and if/else logic statements, but i am not convinced a pure SQL approach is the easiest way to solve this. I use the pyscopg2 library for python to connect python to postgres and send SQL queries from my python script to postgres.